# Gitlab coverage is considering third-party libraries code

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration

I have a ci/cd pipeline in gitlab, project written in `python`.
I'm trying to add coverage.

This is the relevant portion of my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file

```
  script:
    - git config --global http.sslverify false
    - pip install -e .
    - pytest --cov --cov-report term --cov-report xml:coverage.xml
  coverage: '/(?i)total.*? (100(?:\.0+)?\%|[1-9]?\d(?:\.\d+)?\%)$/'
  artifacts:
    reports:
      cobertura: 'coverage.xml'
```

I understand that `/(?i)total.*? (100(?:\.0+)?\%|[1-9]?\d(?:\.\d+)?\%)$/` is a regex that is responsible for taking the percentage in the standard output.
The problem i have is that i get a really low coverage because it seems that gitlab is considering also third-party libraries code in the coverage test.

This is part of my stdout

[image]

(b2badv_api is the module i'm developing and that i want to see if tests cover a good portion of my code).
Is there a way to avoid considering third-party libraries in coverage?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add a directory name to the `--cov` parameter. Our invocation looks like this:

```
py.test --color=no --verbose --ignore=$CI_PROJECT_NAME/migrations --junit-xml=build/pytest/pytest-junit.xml  --cov=$CI_PROJECT_NAME --cov-config=.coveragerc tests
```

Our project structure looks like this:

```
projectname
+ projectname  (source code)
  + migrations (django migrations)
+ tests
```

so the obove command says, `--ignore` the migrations directory, only run `--cov` on the source code directory, and only look for tests in the `tests` directory.